# Program execution stops once I close one of the several windows in swing java program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have 2 windows opened in my Java swing program. If I close one window, the programs stops execution. Is there any way not to stop the execution and play with the other window? Please explain with a sample code as I am new to swings. I tried searching in web, but I think I am lacking proper keywords for this.

Comment: Please elaborate on _stops execution_. Throws exception? Exits JVM?

Comment: you want to run a job in background using threads

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably setting your new windows' close operations to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. Look for places where this happens in your code:

```
JFrame frame = ... ;
// ...
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And replace `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` with `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` for all but the window that you *want* to have exit the application when closed.

Also take a look at the other `ON_CLOSE` values that you can pass in the [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) javadocs.

Comment: *"..for all but the window that you want to have exit the application when closed."*  It also works if `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is used for *every* frame.  The last window closed will exit the application.  This at least applies so long as there are no lingering non-daemon threads. If there are such threads, they should be shut down sensibly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not necessarily. This may be true in Windows, but it's not true for every JVM. From the documentation, "When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM **may** terminate." (Emphasis added.) It's suggested, but not required, that the application terminates, but it's not guaranteed. I can't think of any off the top of my head that do, but I remember finding a couple of them.

Comment: In that case, see my comment re. 'bad practise' above.

Comment: ..actually.  Scratch that and read the next sentence of the docs. that links to [AWT threading issues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html).  It pretty much agrees with me (but says it better).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I stand corrected. :) It's only for Java 5+ that it works this way, but it works nonetheless. The JVM's I'm thinking of must've been 1.4 (we had a couple clients...) so that's where that came from. Thanks for clarifying. Also, I agree, bad practice to have multi-windowed apps.

Answer (score 2):

For the dialog you consider *not* to be be your main window you should ensure that the default close operation does not cause the application to exit:

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably are extending JFrame, therefore when you close the main window it closes.

Please paste some code for further help.